# MS Access: Save form data to 2 tables at the click of a button

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am creating an asset management database with 2 tables (Assets and AssetMovements) and one form (Assets). 
I need to keep records of every asset movement, so every time a new asset is added to the Assets table or the 'Location' value for an existing asset record is modified, the record should be saved to the AssetMovements table. The AssetMovements table is just there to record the transactions.

How can I achieve this? I would be grateful for any pointers I can get, or if anyone can suggest a better method of keeping the movement records.
Thank you.

Comment: which programming language are you using????

Comment: Hi NidhishKrishnan, I'm using Microsoft Access.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing you are using Access 2010, this looks like a good excuse for a [Data Macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) A data macros will run even when the data is updated from outside of MS Access.

I created an Assets table and an AssetMovements table, the AssetMovements table has a field ActionDate with a default value Now(), which sets the date the action occurred.

You will need two macros on the Assets table:

[image: after insert]
[image: after update]

And that is all you need to do, as is shown below.

After adding or changing a record, the data is automatically recorded in the AssetMovements table:

[image: after adding or changing a record]

You can the run a little sample VBScript ...

```
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=z:\docs\demo.accdb" 

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon
sSQL="INSERT INTO Assets (Asset,Location) Values ('Printer',7)"
cn.Execute sSQL

sSQL="Update Assets Set Location=5 Where Asset='Printer'"
cn.Execute sSQL
```

To see that this also updates the AssetMovements table.

[image: After VBScript]

There is also a LogEvent data macro for more complete recording of changes.

Answer (score 1):

The button has a click event that is fired when you click it.  Use VBA to write some code that is executed when the button is clicked.
When you click the button, you would then save the record to Assets. Then copy that record to the AssetMovements table using a query. So, the code will look something like this:

```
Dim OldLocation As String    

Private Sub CmdSave_Click()
   DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
   Dim strSQL
   If OldLocation <> Location.Value Then
      strSQL = "INSERT INTO AssetMovements SELECT T1.* FROM Assets WHERE Assets.ID = "
      strSQL = strSQL & Me.ID
      CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
   OldLocation = Me.Location.OldValue
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
   OldLocation = Me.Location.Value
End Sub
```

This will then copy the current record of the form, using a unique ID (I guessed at AssetID), to the AssetMovement table.

Comment: Thanks Tom. How do I ensure that it only copies records where the 'Location' value has changed?

Comment: Compare Location.Value with Location.OldValue. If different, then copy record.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Would you mind showing me how to do the comparison? I'm an absolute newbie at this.

Comment: Code updated. Btw, the If statement is very basic. I highly recommend you at least take a beginner's tutorial on VBA, or you're going to find yourself lost quite a bit.

Comment: Hi Tom. It didn't save the record to the AssetMovements table. I didn't get any error message also. 
Both tables use the 'ID' as the unique ID.
Below is my final code:

    `Dim strSQL
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    If Location.OldValue <> Location.Value Then
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO AssetMovements SELECT Assets.* FROM Assets WHERE Assets.ID = "
    strSQL = strSQL & me.ID  
    CurrentDB.Execute strSQL 
    End If`

Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: New code listed. The problem was that the oldvalue is only good until the record is saved. Now it saves the oldvalue in a variable before saving.