# Update a field in one table on row insertion in another table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have the following two tables:

**1) Transactions Table**

```
TID   ID
----  --
1212  21
1313  31
1414  21
1515  44
1616  21
1717  31
```

**2) Products Table**

```
PID  Count
---  -----
21       7
31       8
44       9
```

(Original counts value was 10)

I would like to achieve this: when ever I add a transaction in the transaction table, I want to be able to check if the product I'm trying to sell have sufficient quantity in the product table (1 or more) and if it does, allow the addition in the transaction table and decrease the count of the product in the product table.

I tried to do this by going to Table->After Add/After update.. etc. but with no help. Also didn't find resources on the web. I'm using Access 2013.

Comment: How about a data macro http://stackoverflow.com/a/15044797/2548?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this to my needs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need two (2) [data macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) on the [Transactions] table: a Before Change data macro to see if the transaction can be entered ...

[image: BeforeChange.png]

... and an After Insert data macro to update the [Products] table:

[image: AfterInsert.png]